# Is it possible to CD into a file?

Tags: bash, shell, cd

I find a list of files that I need to `cd` to (obviously to the parent directory).

If I do `cd ./src/components/10-atoms/fieldset/package.json` I get the error `cd: not a directory:`, which makes sense.

But isn't there a way to allow for that? Because manipulating the path-string is pretty cumbersome and to me that would make total sense to have an option for that, since `cd` is a directory function and it would be cool that if the path would not end up in a file, it would recursively jump higher and find the "first dir" from the given path.

So `cd ./src/components/10-atoms/fieldset/package.json` would put me into `./src/components/10-atoms/fieldset/` without going on my nerves, telling me that I have chosen a file rather than a dir.

Comment: Use `dirname` to strip off filename

Comment: If the argument is a symbolic link, do you want to jump to the parent of the link or the parent of the linked file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function should do what you need:

```
cdd() { test -d "$1" && cd "$1" || cd $(dirname "$1") ; }
```

If its first argument `"$1"` is a directory, just `cd` into it,
otherwise `cd` into the directory containing it.

This function should be improved to take into account special files such as devices or symbolic links.

Comment: I like this answer more over the one from John Kugelmann, because it does not "override" the base function (that looked like an anti-pattern to me). Since there does not seem to exist another option to do what I ask for, this is probably the most straight forward way.

Comment: It would be useful to borrow from John Kugelmann's answer, in particular the handling of options: `"$1"` is not always the file/directory that you want to display.

Answer (score 6):

You could write a shell function to do it.

```
cd() {
    local args=() arg

    for arg in "$@"; do
        if [[ $arg != -* && -e $arg && ! -d $arg ]]; then
            args+=("$(dirname "$arg")")
        else
            args+=("$arg")
        fi
    done

    builtin cd ${args[0]+"${args[@]}"}
}
```

Put it in your `~/.bashrc` if you want it to be the default behavior. It won't be inherited by shell scripts or other programs so they won't be affected.

It modifies `cd`'s arguments, replacing any file names with the parent directory. Options with a leading dash are left alone. `command cd` calls the underlying `cd` builtin so we don't get trapped in a recursive loop.

<sup>(What is this unholy beast: `${args[0]+"${args[@]}"}`? It's like `"${args[@]}"`, which expands the array of arguments, but it avoids triggering [a bash bug with empty arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394251/why-are-empty-arrays-treated-as-unset-in-bash#58261136) on the off chance that your bash version is 4.0-4.3 and you have `set -u` enabled.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can if you enter a bit longer line (or create dedicated shell script)

```
cd $(dirname ./src/components/10-atoms/fieldset/package.json)
```

If you add it in script it can be :

```
cd $(dirname $1)
```

but you need to execute it on this way:

```
. script_name ./src/components/10-atoms/fieldset/package.json
```

Comment: dirname is what I ended up using, although it doesn't directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this function in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function ccd() {
    TP=$1                    # destination you're trying to reach
    while [ ! -d $TP ]; do   # if $TP is not a directory:
        TP=$(dirname $TP)   # remove the last part from the path
    done                    # you finally got a directory
cd $TP                       # and jump into it
}
```

Usage: `ccd /etc/postfix/strangedir/anotherdir/file.txt` will get you to `/etc/postfix`.